# php create csv file with Japanese language

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I have a php script that creates csv files:

```
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="deposits_withdrawals.csv"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    apache_setenv('no-gzip', 0);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { @ob_end_flush(); }
    ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

example of the results in the csv file:

```
Account ID   Name    requestDate     Type    Method  Amount
22           ‚ ‚³‚  31/07/2012 04:42 deposit Bonus  10,000
22          ‚ ‚³‚   31/07/2012 04:36 deposit Wire   100,000
```

as you can see the name doesnt display the Japanese it displays gibrish.

Comment: Please add what you expect and the raw bytes of the file rather than interpreted text. So far I think the first name should be `舠芠芳`?

Comment: http://www.24k.com.sg/blog-55.html checkout this link.

Comment: yes it should display japenese: 舠芠芳

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the [link above](http://www.24k.com.sg/blog-55.html)

I simply echoed out

```
    echo chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF);
```

and the rest worked just fine!

Comment: If it was supposed to be `舠芠芳` then this makes no sense because your data is in UTF-16LE and that's an UTF-8 BOM...